# Is the scenario used for running android applications the same as running desktop programs?

Tags: java, android

When programming a Java application in desktop, we all know that it would be transformed into a .class file which will run inside JVM later, is it the same when an application runs in android? Because they say android applications are developed by Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though what you said is sort of right, it gets even more in depth then that and has to do more with how the code is converted bytecode. Java virtual machine (JVM)handles it differently then Android Runtime (ART). Here's a [source](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170677-android-art-google-finally-moves-to-replace-dalvik-to-boost-performance-and-battery-life)